# Preventing conflict with module-specific instance variables

Tags: ruby

I have a mixin that can show up in several different areas of our codebase.  In a couple of cases there is, or was, an edge case where the module's use of instance variables conflicted with instance variables used by the classes.

Prepending variable names @__like_this was one solution, but the other we came up with was more sophisticated, having this general structure, in which the accessor methods are closures:

```
module HiddenValue
  def initialize
    hidden_value = nil
    define_singleton_method :value, ->() { hidden_value }
    define_singleton_method :value=, ->(v) { hidden_value = v }
    super
  end
end

class RealClass
  include HiddenValue
  # [...]
end

foo = RealClass.new
foo.value = 123
foo.value # => 123
```

Is this bad style? It means that all methods wanting direct access to the variable must be defined dynamically inside `initialize`, and that could get ugly.  Is there a cleaner way? Or is this the closest we'll get to a module-level "lexical"-ish scoped instance variable?

Comment: It's kind of an interesting pattern, and one I've never seen before. I'm curious why you abandoned the namespaced variables - I would think just calling everything `@hidden_value_var_a`, etc, would be simpler. The biggest problem I see is one you've already identified: you're not cleanly separating behavior from data.

Comment: The question we asked ourselves was "what's the most bullet-proof general solution we can possibly imagine".  With namespaced variables this particular edge case still had a possibility of occurring, possibly years down the track.